# Install DPKG package without updating and upgrating the whole system

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

Have installed Ubuntu 18 that is stable enough so I don't want to change anything except installing additional applications from time to time. But all installation instructions look like this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install <package-name>
```

That means all and every installed package will be upgraded to its latest avaliable  version. I tried to disable system updates and to skip the first two of the above commands but it caused the problem [apt-get install unexpectedly removed Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167823/apt-get-install-unexpectedly-removed-firefox).

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible to install a new application without updating and upgrading anything else?
2. If a new package (in its latest version) cannot coexist with some existing out-of-date packages is it possible to install an older version of this package somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often avoid `sudo apt upgrade` for many weeks when my system is running well. If there is a particular need for example security or new app features I will run it. First I check **Ask Ubuntu** to ensure there are no new bugs reported with `upgrade`.

What I do when I want a new package is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install paxkage-name
```

The `update` doesn't remove software as happened with your Firefox.

The `update` will tell me X packages are upgradable but I simply ignore the message until I have time to study what will get  upgraded.